# mysql query multiple tables and count row

Tags: php, mysql, count

I´m new to MySql and I´m having a problem ordering the result of a query.

I have 2 tables:

Table1 contains the users of my system

```
userId  userName
01      Ken
02      John
03      Bob
04      Steve
```

Table2 contains the followers of each user

```
userId, FollowerId.
02      01
01      02
02      03
02      04
```

so, in this case John has 3 followers: Ken, Bob and Steve.

I would like to generate a third table with 2 columns: users of the database and Number of followers per User. I would like to have the table ordered by Number of followers.

```
  userId NrFollowers
  02    3
  01    1
  03    0
  04    0
```

at the moment I´m using the following code

```
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT userId, userName FROM Table1");
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->store_result();
    $stmt->bind_result($userId, $userName);
        while($stmt->fetch()) {
                //count number followers
                $stmtfl = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM Table2 WHERE userId = (?)");
                $stmtfl->bind_param("s", $userId);
                $stmtfl->execute();
                $stmtfl->store_result();
                $stmtfl->fetch();
                $followCount= $stmtfl->num_rows;

                //now I have $userName and $NrFollowers
```

This solutions is not optimised as required an loop for each databases`s user and does not allow to order the users by number of followers.

Can someone please help me to write the proper Mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sql query, you can try this:

```
select
    tbl1.userId,
    count(distinct tbl2.FollowerId) as NrFollowers
from tbl1
left join tbl2
on tbl1.userId = tbl2.userId
group by tbl1.userId
order by count(distinct tbl2.FollowerId) desc
```

See [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/eef463/7) here.

Comment: Thank you very much. I had a look on the demo. It is exactly what I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT u.usersId, COUNT(f.FollowerId) AS NrFollowers
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN followers f ON f.userId = u.userId
GROUP BY u.userId
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

use below code..

```
SELECT u.usersId, coalesce(COUNT(f.FollowerId) ,0)AS NrFollowers
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN followers f ON f.userId = u.userId
GROUP BY u.userId
order by coalesce(COUNT(f.FollowerId) ,0) desc
```

Comment: Thank you very much